# Node.js Server completing same Function as mobile device on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, tablet

This is my first post on stackoverflow so pls forgive me if I'm making post taht already existis. I'm kinda new into HTML and .js, "know basics guy".

I have a mobile app on tablet that has kisok mode browser and I'm using it to connect to my NodeJS Server on RPI (works). I have a lot of HTML's and .js files already in my project.

What I'm trying to find out:

1. Is it possible to make new seperate HTML or .js file that would do something like remote control with my tablet to server. Example - When I click a button taht same button is clicked on browser on RPI beacuse I have another seperate display on RPI that show same thing and I would use my tablet only as a getter of HTML (so I can show it on tablet) and input method for RPI. (simultaneously on both display but use tablet as input)
2. Or update all existing HTML and .js on server side (harder way, if this thing is even posbile to do)

Thank you very much for further help!

EXtra edit - code

Here is the server side code!

```js
//var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
//var express = require("express")();
var express = require("express");
//var app = require("express")();
var app = express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);

var path = require("path");

//var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var SerialPort = require('serialport');


//previous was app.listen(3000);
http.listen(3000);

//Enabling CORS - for specific localhost port
app.use(function (req, res, next){

 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
 
 next();
});

function handler(req, res){
    console.log(req, res);
}



    var serialPort = new SerialPort.SerialPort("/dev/ttyAMA0", {
        baudrate: 9600,
        dataBits: 8,
        parity: "none",
        stopBits: 1,
        flowControl: false
    });

    var counter = 0;

    serialPort.on("open", function () {
        console.log("open");
        var service = new Service();

        serialPort.on("data", function (data) {
            var hexData = data.toString('hex');
            console.log(data, hexData);
            io.emit('hit', data);
        });
    });


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Connected');
 
 //nsmrcek - custom code for accepting data from client side
 socket.on("message1",function(data){

 });
 socket.on("message2",function(data){

 });
 socket.on("message3",function(data){

 });
 socket.on("message4", function(data){

 });
 socket.on("message5", function(data){

 });

});




app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

//app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname,

app.get("/home",function(req,res,next){
 //res.send("OK");
 //if fails path incorrect
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
 //res.render("index.html");
});


function Service() {
    this.mapCodeToHit = function (data) {
 "data send from little homemade CPU board via serial port to RPI server" }
```

I hope this is enough code so You can instruct me where to put more code to simulate click on evry other client while clicking button on one of the clients (alawys 2 clients)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created a websocket connection that ran through your server and pushed the updated state of the button to the connected clients this would certainly be possible. I can't give a detailed answer without seeing your code but you could start with the socket.io docs here and ask more questions as you get started.

http://socket.io/

Comment: yes, I'm using socket.io for taht, my question is now can I get buttons id from one browser and simulate click on another (i will have to find all button ID's, there is like 100 buttons with great deal of code in HTML and .js) or how You said it to push update state of button to the conected clients. I'm sorry but I can't put so much code here (socket.io version 1.4.5). I have engine for game in .js, main menu, it says something about node-pushserver. All I need to know what code to use for such situatin, and throu time I will find where to put it (i think). Sorry for not being more specific

Comment: push.js added in question

Comment: server.js added in question